# User Interaction is Disabled when Adding Animation to One UIButton

Tags: ios, animation

I have a certain UIButton that I want to animate repeatedly (fade-in, fade-out) all the time when the Main View is displayed. But I have other objects that need user interactions such as TableView and other UIButtons.

After adding the animation, the app doesn't respond to any user interaction even though I have already included the `UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction`.

Here's my code:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0
                          delay:0.0
                     options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction|UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat|UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse
                     animations:^{
                         sendOrderButton.alpha = 0.0;
                     }
                     completion:nil
     ];
```

Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: See Kurt Amlund's answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7888116/user-interaction-on-an-animated-uibutton

Comment: @basvk, thank you for your answer. But my problem is I couldn't perform any interaction on all of the objects present in the current view. I can add another view for the animated object but how about the other views that I couldn't scroll or click?

Comment: i have tried your code and it worked fine for me, i have created button through code which you have used in animation block, may be you have some different issue.

Answer (score 0):

[Apple Document says](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622577-userinteractionenabled?language=objc): During an animation, user interactions are temporarily disabled for all views involved in the animation, regardless of the value in this property. You can disable this behavior by specifying the UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction option when configuring the animation. Hope below code snippet should work for you as well

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0
                          delay:0.0
                     options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction|UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat|UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse| UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                     animations:^{
                         sendOrderButton.alpha = 0.0;
                     }
                     completion:nil
     ];
```